# How to create a Truststore that includes all certificates from a folder with Ansible?

Tags: java, ansible, truststore

I want to automate the task of creating a Truststore that includes all certificates from a directory.

I only found an Ansible module that automates the creation of a Truststore with a predefined set of certificates (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/java_cert_module.html). In contrast to that I want to have all certificates from a certain folder without describing each of it in the config.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should combine `java_cert` with `with_fileglob` like this:

```
- name: "Create my own truststore"
  java_cert:
    keystore_path: "mytrust.store"
    keystore_pass: "changeit"
    keystore_create: "yes"
    state: "present"
    cert_path: "{{ item }}"
  with_fileglob:
    - "{{ playbook_dir}}/certs/*.crt"
```